# How to get all the elements of an array that are divisible with 3 and then sum them thogether?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, sizeof, function-definition

I dont know how to get the code to print out the elements that are divisable with 3 and the print out the sum of those elements , can someone help me do it , thanks for your time!

Code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int sum(int arr[]){
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    int sum = 0;
    for (int y=0;y<n;y++){
        sum += arr[y];
        printf("%d",sum);
    }
}

int main() {
    int F[5] = {1,3,5,9,8};
    int s = 0;
     for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
       if (F[i]%3 == 0) {
           int diviz[] = {F[i]};
           printf("%d\n",diviz[0]);
           sum(diviz);
       }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Expected Output:

```
3
9
12
```

Actual Output:

```
3
349
910
```

Idk how to solve this issue

Comment: `int sum = 0; for (int i=0;i<5;i++) { if (F[i]%3 == 0) { sum += F[i]; } }`?

Comment: As *part* of the problem with the code you currently have, when declared as an argument `int arr[]` is really the same as `int *arr`. And the size of a pointer is the size of the pointer itself. Please refresh the chapters on arrays and pointers in your text-books.

Comment: it prints:
```
3
9
10977641
```

Comment: Which will draw your attention to the error in `int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);` -- which is equivalent to `sizeof (a_pointer) / sizeof (int)`

Comment: Functions receive the address of the first element of an array... nothing more... Consider the pair `argc` and `argv` that are used to pass command line parameters to an executable. `argv` alone carries no information about how many arguments there are. (Some know of another technique that is irrelevant to this question...) Functions need at least two parameters to deal correctly with arrays that may have varying numbers of elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main() {
    int F[5] = {1,3,5,9,8};
    int s = 0;
     for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
       if (F[i]%3 == 0) {
           s = s + F[i];
           printf("%d",F[i]); 
       }
    }
    printf("%d",s); //print sum total 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Code dumps" with no words of explanation are not normally considered to be adequate answers... Congrats on scoring points... I recommend you expend more effort in explaining what was wrong and what is now right... Simply doing the homework assignments for people posting questions is considered bad practice on SO...

Answer (score 1):

This function declaration

```
int sum(int arr[]){
```

is adjusted by the compiler to the declaration

```
int sum(int *arr){
```

That is within the function the variable `arr` has the pointer type `int *`.

Thus the declaration with sizeof expression

```
int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
```

is equivalent to

```
int n = sizeof( int * ) / sizeof( int );
```

and yields either 2 or 1 depending on the size of the pointer.

On the other hand, this call of the function

```
   int diviz[] = {F[i]};
   printf("%d\n",diviz[0]);
   sum(diviz);
```

in any case does not make a great sense because instead of passing the original array you are passing an array that contains only one element. And the for loop in main is redundant.

You need explicitly to pass the number of elements in the array.

So the function can look like

```
long long int sum( const int arr[], size_t n, int divisor )
{
    long long int sum = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( arr[i] % divisor == 0 ) sum += arr[i];
    }

    return sum;
}
```

And the function can be called like

```
int arr[] = {1,3,5,9,8};
const size_t N = sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( *arr );

int divisor = 3;

printf( "The sum of elements divisible by %d = %lld\n", divisor, sum( arr, N, divisor ) );
```

The function will be more safer if to add a check whether `divisor` is passed equal to `0` as for example

```
long long int sum( const int arr[], size_t n, int divisor )
{
    long long int sum = 0;

    if ( divisor != 0 )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            if ( arr[i] % divisor == 0 ) sum += arr[i];
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```